# I want to project 2 input to 3 floors

Tags: laptop, hdmi, video-camera, projector, hdtv

I am a camera man in my church and I want to add lyrics, bible verse input too to the projector, which is currently in first floor only. 
I want a suggestion for the equipments required for camera laptop and long range wiring.

---

### Current scenario:

Camera and laptop output in HDMI but inputs for projector and it's long wiring are in AV wire. As of now HDMI camera connects to AV cable with converter and there's a AV splitter 1 in 4 out box. Splitting into 2, 2 for each floors, men & women.

### Changes required:

Church has 5 floors. Gf 1f 2f 3f 4f Display to above 3 floors (If hdmi recommended for projector I can) camera's output to camera floor(1f) not required only laptop's required.
A projector or TV (confused) for lyrics and verse(1f). Equipments for this setup from laptop to display.

### How I planned:

I already have 2X4 (2 in 4 out with selector button), hdmi splitter for which 
2 male-to-male HDMi required connecting camera to splitter and laptop to splitter and output to hdmi to AV converter